# Is $f(x) = 1/x$ measurable on the entire real line?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

To show the measurability of a function say $f(x)$ we only need to show that the set

$$A= \{x : f(x) > y\}$$

In this case

$$A = \{x : 1/x > y\}
  = \{x : x < 1/y\}$$

If $y = 0$ the set is empty and empty sets are measurable, I'm not sure what happens if $y$ is not zero

Comment: If $y=0$ then $\{x : 1/x>y\}$ is not empty.

Comment: When $y>0$, $A$ (n your notation) cannot have negative values, the set $\{x:x<1/y\}$ contains negative values. Consider the sign of numbers carefully. A graph of $f$ my help you. For $y<0$, $A$ is the union of two disjoint intervals.

Comment: \begin{align}
\{f>y\}:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}:f(x)>y\}=\left\{\begin{matrix} (0,1/y) &\text{if} & y>0\\
(0,\infty) &\text{if}&y=0\\
(-\infty,1/y)\cup(0,\infty) &\text{if}&y<0
\end{matrix}
\right.
\end{align} in each case, the preimage $\{f>y\}$ is a Borel set (in fact open, and hence Borel). This means that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Thanks, that's how I've been trying to make it look like, now I have a better understanding of how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to adopt the slightly different notation
$$A_y = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}:\; 1/x>y\}.$$
The set $A_y$ is clearly open for every fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and hence measurable. Specifically, if $y>0$  the equation defining $A_y$ can be rearranged as you have done:
$$A_y = \{x>0:\; x<1/y\},$$
and if $y=0$, as GEdgar has noted, $A_0$ is not at all empty (and still open)
$$A_0 = \{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}:\; 1/x>0\} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}:\; x>0\} = \mathbb{R}^+.$$ Finally if $y<0$, $A_y$ is the union of two open intervals.
I should also mention that pretty much any set you'll encounter will naturally be measurable, as in order to produce an example of non-measurable set one has to work [real hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: It probably should be $A_y = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \: : \:1/x > y\}$, which is of course a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks, answer edited

Comment: Thanks, edit made

Comment: @OliverDiaz yes when $y<0$ the level sets are slightly different than when $y\ge0$ but I don't see why you want to put so much emphasis on this. I believe the reader can figure that out by themself, what matters here is $A_y$ is open and that's the simplest way I can see to recognize $A_y$ as measurable. You are right though that I was still imprecise with the definition of $A_y$, thanks for pointing that out. I believe you should find my answer satisfying now.

Comment: @TotoPasta: I don't care much about the case $y<0$, that can be left for the OP. But your answer is wrong in any event. $\{f>y\}=(0,1/y)$ for all $y>0$, not $\{x:x<1/y\}=(-\infty,1/y)$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I have already corrected that.